# Enlarging top-border width on a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I enlarge a top-border of one cell? I've tried to set a bigger width to that cell. But it doesn't work.

I'm trying to enlarge the top-border cell which has `tags_footer` as a class. In fact, I'm trying also to make border width equal to the width of `tags_forums + tags_description + tags_msgs`

Here is code **Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/pyXBk/

**HTML :**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tags_forums">Forums</td>
        <td class="tags_description">Description</td>
        <td class="tags_msgs">msgs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tags_body">
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td> DFG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tags_footer">Last msg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
.tags_forums {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.tags_description {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.tags_msgs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.tags_footer{
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want a bar at the bottom of your .tags_body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML, not the CSS:

```
<td colspan="3" class="tags_footer">Last msg</td>
```

You need this table cell to span three columns, and that does it. The `colspan` attribute is what you need.

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pyXBk/2/

Comment: thank you, 6 minutes to become able to validate. Otherwise, how can I make smaller the `tags_description` cell, please ?

Comment: the `.tags_description` is already as small as it can get with a shrink-to-fit width (default value).  If you want to make it smaller, you can set a with, for example, `width: 3em` and then force the word to wrap using `word-break: break-all`, see for example, http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pyXBk/3/ However, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: can you please explain me what the signification of `em` :p

Comment: `em` is a length unit used in CSS, equivalent to the width of an uppercase letter 'M'

Comment: Ok, thank you ! Look I've tried this using pixel width, but it doesn't work :http://jsfiddle.net/pyXBk/4/

Comment: You need to add 'word-break: break-all;' otherwise the word won't wrap and it will force the cell to expand its width to enclose the content.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!! if I had the rights to upvote, I would have upvoted all you comments and your answer !!!!!!!!!!!